# Unit testing inside the main project

Tags: unit-testing, testing

Usually, unit tests are built in a separate project/executable.

Ideally, components under tests should have a small number of mockable dependencies, allowing us to do this, among other benefits.

But this is sometimes hard or requires a lot of effort. Some examples are legacy code, code that depends on elements that are difficult to mock (like a complex hardware device poorly documented), etc.

A way to test this kind of code is by compiling the project and making some hooks where we can run tests. They could be enabled via a command-line option or a compile-time switch. For example, we can perform initialization and then run a testing function. We can also add some testing methods to alter the state of the program and other tricks. This gives us access to everything we could need and does not force us to do extensive refactors or create premature abstractions.

Benefits:

- Makes it easier to start testing
- No need for a testing harness that might not exist
- Tests are closer to the real world
- It can be used to bootstrap a proper suite of tests once we start decoupling
- Better than nothing

Drawbacks:

- Slower
- A testing harness can be useful
- Good unit tests usually lead to a better design. We don't get that here
- Mixing testing code and production code doesn't seem like a good idea

To some extent, this is like using the whole project as a test harness.

What are your thoughts about this? Is there a book or a blog explaining this kind of technique? Projects that use it? Does it even have a name? I think that in "Working Effectively with Legacy Code" they mention something, but I haven't read it (yet).

Comment: What you're describing are not unit tests. That doesn't mean they don't have value, but they're not unit tests. Rather than worrying about this now, just go and read *Working Effectively with Legacy Code* (note you have the title wrong).

Comment: If you can have a suit of tests which you can run against production environment without affecting working state (state of the app remain same after test suit is complete) - I would say this can be very useful for users and developers. Just imagine that every time user starts an application, application will execute self test - isn't that what was done in early days of programming ;)

Comment: @PhilipKendall What I have in mind would be something in between unit tests and integration tests, depending on each test.

Comment: In Rust, it is normal that the same file contains normal code and the unit tests for that code. The code for the tests is guarded behind compile-time feature flags. This works extraordinarily well for me, and also makes it easy to test “private” code without tortured test cases or excessive mocks. Unfortunately, other languages have worse support for compile-time feature flags. E.g. C-style `#ifdef` directives provide less confidence that the code being tested is similar to the code being put into production.

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is indeed mentioned in "Working Effectively with Legacy Code", not with a special name, but more as a receipe:

- For an existing code base, it is often easier to start with "higher level" tests (which is the term Feathers uses to distinguish them from unit tests). These tests don't require the "inner structure" of a larger system to be changed. When those tests are in place, they allow to resolve inner dependencies with more confidence, so refactoring towards unit testing becomes possible.
- Feathers suggests to use "seams" for this - places in code where one can change the behaviour without editing it in place. Unfortunately, most legacy code does not naturally provide such seams. This is *"The Legacy Code Dilemma"* (see WEWLC chapter 2):

  > When we change code, we should have tests in place. To put tests in place, we often have to change code.

The challenge is to find the right balance between a few changes to the code to gain testability (for example, utilizing the preprocessor), and the risk by making the code less maintainable by introducing too many hooks and preprocessor statements.

When you find out that the least intrusive option for adding seams to existing code is to start at the "outer layers", then fine, go ahead with it and don't overthink it. Just be careful not to sacrifice readibility for testability, and try to keep the changes to the existing code small, to minimize the risk of introducing bugs into working code.

Answer (score 2):

In general, this sort of thing is not done. As soon as the tests are available to users they become a security risk and a fairly significant maintenance cost (https://xkcd.com/1172/). Test utilities still tend to be separate executables (so you can package them separately) that import shared libraries to get at the troublesome hardware or other limiting factor.

One exception to this tends to be video games. They often leave some of the testing infrastructure available as cheats or as an API to allow for mods.

Comment: You don't need to make anything available to users.

`They could be enabled via a command-line option or a compile-time switch`.

Also, a lot of projects are web-based (so developer tools are available) or even Open Source.

Comment: @JosuGoñi, command-line options *will* be found out by users and thus pose a security risk if they are present in the production executable. Compile-time switches will create a separate executable.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Exactly, compile-time switches will create a separate executable that does not have test code.

Comment: @JosuGoñi, the big disadvantage of compile switches is that in the sources test code and production code are intertwined, increasing the maintenance effort.

Comment: Not to mention, it’s harder to implement in almost every language compared to just pulling in the library you’re testing.

Comment: Rust has first-class support for distinguishing tests via compile-time feature flags. It works pretty well IMO, but only because Rust was carefully designed to do this safely. I would feel way less confident about this if my compile-time feature flag was just a C preprocessor style `#ifdef`.